# how to use linq with two related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hello i got a problem while using two related entities in a dotnet project
i have two entities table and reservation and i need to get the table that is reserved for tomorrow but the date is seted in the reservation table
here's the code

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> IReservation { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public DateTime DateReservation { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public virtual Table table { get; set; }
}
public class RestaurantContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Table> tTable { set; get; }
    public DbSet<Reservation> tReservation { set; get; }
    public RestaurantContext() : base("RestaurentDB") {     
    }
}
class TableRepository
{
    RestaurantContext rc = null;

    public TableRepository()
    {
        rc = new RestaurantContext();
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        rc.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void AddTable(Table m)
    {
        rc.tTable.Add(m);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Table> GetAllTables() {
        return rc.tTable.ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Table> GetTablesReserverdTomorrow() {
       ....
    }
```

Here i need to get the table which are reserved for tomorrow
i tried

```
var res=rc.tReservation.Where(r => (r.DateReservation == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))).ToList();
            var res1 = rc.tTable.Select(r => res.Contains(r.Id));
            return res1;
```

but it seems theres an error

> Argument1: Cannot convert from int to Reservation

Comment: Please specify the error you get

Comment: sorry :) check the edit

Comment: To get all tables for tomorrow: return rc.tReservation.Where(r => r.DateReservation == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)).Select( r => r.Table ).ToList();

Comment: @SirRufo the syntaxe is even wrong 'return var res...' thats not correct but even if it is that will return reservation table only i need to return tTable

Comment: and @TomRedfern check the error please

Comment: @David's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use navigation within your query, like:

```
return rc.tReservation
    .Include(reservation => reservation.Table)
    .Where(r => (r.DateReservation == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)))
    .Select(reservation => reservation.table).ToList();
```

Comment: says cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type

Comment: `return rc.tReservation
    .Where(r => (r.DateReservation == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)))
    .Select(reservation => reservation.table).ToList();` works

Comment: How to use .include is depending on used ef version. In older versions it is even not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In your case res is IEnumerable, it contains Reservation instances, not int values. By the logic of your code, it seems that table and resrvation should have the same id to get a result.
I think you should change your code to:

```
var res=rc.tReservation.Where(r => (r.DateReservation == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))).ToList();
        var res1 = rc.tTable.Where(r => res.Any(resItem=>resItem.Id == r.Id));
        return res1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are receiving a linq to entities sql exception. this means that you are trying to use methods not available in sql server.

I have taken a different approach to your problem:

step #1: the repository method introduced which al

```
/// <summary>
/// A method that allows you to get all tables reserved in a specific period. tables are only returned if they are reserverd.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="start"></param>
/// <param name="end"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<Table> GetAllReservedTables(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return this.rc.tReservation
        // filter by date range
        .Where(x => x.DateReservation >= start && x.DateReservation <= end)

        // ensure table is returned
        .Select(x => x.table);
}
```

Step 2: calling the repository method and ensuring you have the right date range, which is tomorrow:

```
    TableRepository repo = new TableRepository();

    // figure out the 24 hour period you need to find reserved tables for
    // it is advisible when searching by date to use a date range instead of once specific date
    // the start date and end date will satisfy the 24 hour period of tomorrow.

    // get start tomorrow
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(1);

    // get end of tomorrow
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(2);

    // call the repository method with the date range (the 24 hour period for tomorrow)
    var tablesForTomorrow = repo.GetAllReservedTables(startDate, endDate);

    // dispaly data in console
    foreach(var table in tablesForTomorrow)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Table Number: #{0}", table.Numero);
    }
```

please see the below complete solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservationTableIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TableRepository repo = new TableRepository();

            // step #1 - figure out the 24 hour period you need to find reserved tables for
            // it is advisible when searching by date to use a date range instead of once specific date
            // the start date and end date will satisfy the 24 hour period of tomorrow.

            // get start tomorrow
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(1);

            // get end of tomorrow
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(2);

            // call the repository method with the date range (the 24 hour period for tomorrow)
            var tablesForTomorrow = repo.GetAllReservedTables(startDate, endDate);

            // dispaly data in console
            foreach(var table in tablesForTomorrow)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table Number: #{0}", table.Numero);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    public class Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Reservation> IReservation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reservation
    {
        public DateTime DateReservation { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public virtual Table table { get; set; }
    }
    public class RestaurantContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table> tTable { set; get; }
        public DbSet<Reservation> tReservation { set; get; }
        public RestaurantContext() : base("RestaurentDB") {     
        }
    }

    public class TableRepository
    {
        RestaurantContext rc = null;

        public TableRepository()
        {
            rc = new RestaurantContext();
        }
        public void Commit()
        {
            rc.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void AddTable(Table m)
        {
            rc.tTable.Add(m);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Table> GetAllTables()
        {
            return rc.tTable.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A method that allows you to get all tables reserved in a specific period. tables are only returned if they are reserverd.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="start"></param>
        /// <param name="end"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<Table> GetAllReservedTables(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            return this.rc.tReservation
                // filter by date range
                .Where(x => x.DateReservation >= start && x.DateReservation <= end)

                // ensure table is returned
                .Select(x => x.table);
        }
    }

}
```